# Why I am not able to Pop Element from stack using Linked List Implementation?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

Problem:

I am not able to pop the element second time.
For Example I have 4,3,2,1 with 4 on top of stack.I am not able to delete 3,2

> Can anyone guide me why?

Below is the Stack Implementation :

```
public static void push(int data){
        if(head==null){
            Node newNode=new Node(data);
            head=newNode;
        }else{
            Node newNode1=new Node(data);
            newNode1.next=head;
            head=newNode1;
    }

    }
    public static int pop(){
        if(head==null){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            Node temp=head;
            int a=temp.data;
            temp=null;
            return a;
        }
    }
    public static void traverse(){
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp!=null){
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp=temp.next;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Were you expecting `temp=null;` to actually do anything to the list?

Comment: you have accessed the `head` as `temp.data` and returns that value. But you didn't have done something more with `head`... * _pshh, assign `temp.next()` to head_ *

Comment: You are missing `head = temp.next` which will move your head to next one and delete/remove previous one.

Comment: @user2357112 Wanted to node as null on top of the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem in your pop method

```
  public static int pop(){
    if(head==null){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        Node temp=head;
        head = head.next;
        int a=temp.data;
        temp=null;
        return a;
    }
}
```

you forgot to move your head to the next node.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't removing the element from list, you'r just making the variable that points to head to be Null. That doesn't change the linkedList.

You have two options:

1. Remove element from list using built-in function from linkedlist.
2. Change list.head and make it points to next element.

In case 2, you have to add the following on pop method:

```
 head = head.next;
```